# Update environment variables from TeamCity build step

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, teamcity

In my build configuration I have environment variables for major, minor and patch version numbers.

I am trying to write a build step that checks the name of the branch and if it is a release branch with a higher version than the current env vars, I want to update them.

I have tried setting the variables, but when I go the 'Parameters' tab it still shows the old value.

I am writing a Powershell script, and have tried:

`Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='major.version' value='2']"`

`Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.major.version' value='2']"`

`$Env:major.version = 2`

Comment: Where these environment variables which you want to update are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the settings of the TeamCity build configuration, you need to use [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings).
e.g. curl -u username:password "https://teamcity.corp.com/app/rest/buildTypes/id:%system.teamcity.buildType.id%/parameters/major.version" --request PUT --header "Content-Type: text/plain"

You will need to provide creentials of a user who has "Edit Project" permission.

Note: ##teamcity[setParameter... changes the parameter only for the following steps of the same build.

Comment: Thanks! In case it helps anyone the exact command I ran was:
`curl -v --basic --user <username>:<password> --request PUT http://<teamcity url>/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<build id>/parameters/env.major.version --data 2 --header "Content-Type: text/plain"`
My teamcity url was slightly different which confused me for a while